# Especific order google script (range.sort)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my issue, I am trying to order a table in google sheets, I am currently using the following code:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var s = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "B3:G100";
  var lastrow = s.getLastRow();

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort([{column: columnToSortBy, ascending: true}])
  }
}
```

My table looks something like the following:

**Table**
[image]

The code works fine, but if for example I already have a list that goes from 1 - 10 and I change the number one, it sorts the list and puts this new number 1 below the older number one.

What I want is: If I put 1, I want it to be above the older 1, if I put a 3, I want it to be above the older number 3 and so on...

¿Is it possible to order this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write `2.9` or `0.9` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes that works, but I need the list to be integer and from 1 to 10, That way could even end up having negative numbers...
Thank you!

Comment: To answer your question, Yes. It's possible. You'd need to write your own custom  [compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for sort. Notice that you'll be working with 2D arrays, when you `getValues()`. Here's a [basic tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) to get you started.